# Slice substrings from long string to a list in python

Tags: python, regex

In python I have long string like (of which I removed all breaks)

```
stringA = 'abcdefkey:12/eas9ghijklkey:43/e3mnop'
```

What I want to do is to search this string for all occurrences of `"key:"`, then extract the "values" following `"key:"`.
One further complication for me is that I don't know how long these values belonging to key are (e.g. `key:12/eas9` and `key:43/e3`). All I do know is that they do have to end with a digit whereas the rest of the string does not contain any digits.

This is why my idea was to slice from the indices of `key` plus the next say 10 characters (e.g. `key:12/eas9g`) and then work backward until `isdigit()` is false.

I tried to split my initial string (that did contain breaks):

```
stringA_split = re.split("\n", stringA)

for linex in stringA_split:
  index_start = linex.rfind("key:")
  index_end = index_start + 8
  print(linex[index_start:index_end]
  #then work backward
```

However, inserting line breaks does not help in any way as they are meaningless from a pdf-to-txt conversion.

How would I then solve this (e.g. as a start with getting all indices of '"key:"' and slice this to a list)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

>>> re.findall('key:(\d+[^\d]+[\d])', stringA)
['12/eas9', '43/e3']
```

`\d+`  # One or more digits.

`[^\d]+`  # Everything except a digit (equivalent to `[\D]`).

`[\d]`  # The final digit

`(\d+[^\d]+[\d])`  # The group of the expression above

`'key:(\d+[^\d]+[\d])'`  # 'key:' followed by the group expression

If you want `key:` in your result:

```
>>> re.findall('(key:\d+[^\d]+[\d])', stringA)
['key:12/eas9', 'key:43/e3']
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your definition of what defines a value, but I think this will get you what you described

```
import re
stringA = 'abcdefkey:12/eas9ghijklkey:43/e3mnop'
for v in stringA.split('key:'):
    ma = re.match(r'(\d+\/.*\d+)', v)
    if ma:
        print ma.group(1)
```

This returns:

```
12/eas9
43/e3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply just one RE that gets all the keys into an array of tuples:

```
import re
p=re.compile('key\:(\d+)\/([^\d]+\d)')
ret=p.findall(stringA)
```

After the execution, you have:

```
ret 
[('12', 'eas9'), ('43', 'e3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: a better answer was posted above. I misread the original question when proposing to reverse here, which really wasn't necessary. Good luck!

If you know that the format is always key:, what if you reversed the string and rex for :yek? You'd isolate all keys and then can reverse them back

```
import re
# \w is alphanumeric, you may want to add some symbols
rex = re.compile("\w*:yek")

word = 'abcdefkey:12/eas9ghijklkey:43/e3mnop'
matches = re.findall(rex, word[::-1])
matches = [match[::-1] for match in matches]
```